# Selecting from dropdownlist causes page to open in new window

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have an asp.net page using vb.net. There is a linkbutton that opens up a store's website in a separate tab. This is done using Javascript. There is also a dropdownlist that contains coat sizes. The dropdownlist posts back.

Here is the problem I'm having.

The user clicks on the linkbutton that takes him to the store's website in a separate tab. The store's website does in fact come up in a tab. However "AFTER" the user does this, if the user selects a size from the dropdownlist the original page opens up in a new tab. This should not happen. Selecting a coat size from the dropdownlist should not cause the original page to open in a new tab after clicking on the linkbutton. Can someone let me know how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Server Code Below.

```vb
Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim size As String
    size = DropDownList1.SelectedValue
End Sub

Protected Sub LinkButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim link As String
    link = "http://"
    link = link + "www.google.com"
    Response.Redirect(link)
End Sub
```

Page Code Below.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
            onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
            <asp:ListItem>Sm</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Med</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Lg</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>XLg</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <br /><br />

        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
            onclick="LinkButton1_Click" OnClientClick="SetTarget();">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
    </form>
</body>

<script type = "text/javascript">

    function SetTarget() {
        document.forms[0].target = "_blank";
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I think it's because you set the target of form[0] to `_blank` upon clicking the link button, any subsequent postbacks (such as selecting the dropdownlist item) will open in new tab.

Comment: Do you have to set the URL onclick? If not, just use a `HyperLink` control and set its `Target` property rather than the form's.